# detect when video finishes and redirect to web page

Tags: javascript, flash, jwplayer, swfobject

I've found various ideas on how to detect when a web video ends, but can't get the syntax right for the way I'm using javascript to play the video. Note that I'm using version 4 of the jwplayer.

Here is the HTML that uses swfobject.js and player.swf. It works fine, but I want to add code that detects when the video has finished at will then redirect to a web location using - window.location.href = http://www.webpage.com

Any help will be very appreciated! Here's the full page of HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type='text/javascript' src='swfobject.js'></script>
</head>
<body lang=EN-US bgcolor='#000000'>

<center>
<p id='preview'></p>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var so = new SWFObject('player.swf','player1','640','381','9');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addParam('flashvars','&file=mymovie.m4v&bufferlength=3&autostart=true&controlbar=bottom');
so.write('preview');

</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use our JS API - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

And, use our JW Embedder (Not SwfObject) - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/blog/15827/using-the-jw-embedder-to-embed-your-player

Then, the set up will look something like this:

```
<h2>Redirecting on complete</h2>

<div id="container">This'll be the player</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("container").setup({
    file:"bunny.mp4",
    flashplayer:"player.swf",
    height:400,
    width:600,
    events:{
        onComplete: function() {
            window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Hope that helps!